# Can Perl's MsOffice::Word::HTML::Writer edit existing Word documents?

Tags: perl, ms-word

I have a Word document and want to add to it an image logo, I found this module from CPAN `MsOffice::Word::HTML::Writer`
which can manipulate new word documents like for example writing image

```
$doc->write("<img src='files/my_image.gif'>");
```

My question how I can open with this module `MsOffice::Word::HTML::Writer` an already existed word document, as from the [`new` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/MsOffice::Word::HTML::Writer#new) seems create a new Word document, but there are no option to open already created document.

Answer (score 0):

The [examples in the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MsOffice::Word::HTML::Writer#write) show that you have to attach an image first, then reference it:

```
$doc->attach("my_image.gif", $path_to_my_image);
$doc->write("<img src='files/my_image.gif'>");
```

But the module docs say that it's for making Word docs, not editing them:

> The present module is one way to programatically generate documents targeted for Microsoft Word (MsWord). It doesn't need MsWord to be installed, and doesn't even require a Win32 machine (which is why the module is not in the Win32 namespace).

Comment: Thanks , though my question if its possible to edit already created word document

Comment: When I read your title, I do not see the question you think you are asking. However, there are various Win32::OLE modules that may help.